# How does iframe injection happen to a web page?

Tags: security, iframe

I recently learned about iframe injection and have seen some examples. I am wondering, how does a hacker get access to a website in the first place? Do they have to have access to the html files on the host machine?

Comment: Well one way is if you have HTML access to edit your profile on a website. In a lot of cases iframe injection can be completely harmless if users *only* have HTML access and steps are taken to ensure that their code does not contain any JavaScript, but removing JavaScript from an HTML string is usually very difficult to achieve.

Comment: Good answer, I remember Myspace had that back in the day. I'm surprised they allowed that, it seems like it would have been a big vulnerability.

Comment: If you manage to have JavaScript access to a website, you can do a lot of scary things quite easily now with [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) which did not exist [back in the days of Myspace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samy_(computer_worm))